# How do I use TypeORM with Ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, typeorm

TypeORM homepage *specifically mentions* supporting the Ionic platform but I can't see any way to get it to work.  If I create a new Ionic project and then run typeorm init it "does its thing" but then breaks the actual Ionic project due to overwriting several files which Ionic needs.

I see from googling that using TypeORM with Ionic is possible and people are doing it but how do I go from a blank ionic project to getting TypeORM in to it?

I also assume that I would use the "cordova" database driver as it would be the easiest way to get it up and running, but I could be wrong.  Any help with this would be great also.  Thanks!

Comment: Downvoter please comment what makes this a lousy question?

Answer (score 0):

Well the getting started guide of TypeORM specifically mentions that some files may get overwritten if they already exist:

> You can also run typeorm init on exist node project, but be careful -
>   it may override some files you may already have.

So run the `init` command in an emtpy folder and then copy/merge the files. You can copy the following files/folders as they do not exist in an ionic project (except if you have pages that are called `entity` or `migration`):

- `/src/entity` to `/src/entity`
- `/src/migration` to `/src/migration`
- `/ormconfig.json` to `/ormconfig.json`

And you will have to manually merge the following two files (simply add the dependencies/configurations to the existing ionic files):

- `/package.json` into `/package.json`
- `/tsconfig.json` inot `/tsconfig.json`

You do need the `index.ts` file because your ionic project already has an entry point.

[Here](https://github.com/typeorm/ionic-example) is an example ionic project which uses TypeORM.

---

Of course you also have to install the npm packages needed which are mentioned [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm#installation).

Comment: It does specifically say that however it doesn't go into how to set up TypeORM for Ionic despite specifically saying that it supports it.  I'll do what you suggested and give it a go :) thank you!

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps for integrating TypeORM with Ionic 4 and Angular.

After creating the project, you can install and integrate TypeORM as follows.

Open a new terminal, navigate to your project and install TypeORM from  `npm`:

```sh
$ cd ionic-project
$ npm install typeorm --save
```

Next, install Node.js types:

```sh
$ npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

Since we'll be doing testing in the browser we also need to install  `sql.js`:

```sh
$ npm install sql.js --save
```

Next, open the  `tsconfig.json`  file and add  `"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]`  under  `compilerOptions`  if it's not already there.

Next, open the  `src/tsconfig.app.json`  and change accordingly:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "typeorm": ["node_modules/typeorm/browser"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

### Adding a Custom Webpack Configuration

Next, create a custom Webpack configuration file in the root of your project:

```sh
$ touch custom.webpack.config.js
```

Open the  `custom.webpack.config.js`  file and add the following code:

```js
const webpack = require('webpack');
console.log('The custom config is used');
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            'window.SQL': 'sql.js/js/sql.js'
        }),
        new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/typeorm$/, function (result) {
            result.request = result.request.replace(/typeorm/, "typeorm/browser");
        })
    ],
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    }
};
```

Next, head back to your terminal and install the  `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`  and  `@angular-builders/dev-server`  packages from npm:

```sh
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/custom-webpack
$ npm install --save @angular-builders/dev-server
```

The  **@angular-builders/custom-webpack v7.4.3**  and **@angular-builders/dev-server v7.3.1 **  packages will be installed.

The  [`@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular)  builder makes use of the custom webpack builder to get webpack configuration. Unlike the default  `@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server`  it doesn't use`@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`  configuration to run the development server. If you use  `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic`  along with  `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser`,  `ng serve`  will run with custom configuration provided in the latter.

Now, open the  `angular.json`  file, locate the  `projects -> app -> architect -> build -> builder`  entry and swap  **@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser**  with  **@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser**.

Next, under the  `options`  object, add  `"customWebpackConfig": {"path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"}`:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./custom.webpack.config.js"
            },
```

Next, change the  `builder`  property under the  `serve`  property to  `@angular-builders/dev-server:generic`:

```
  "projects": {
    "app": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {},
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/dev-server:generic",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app:build"
          },
```

Now, if you serve your application again, the custom Webpack configuration will be used and you should see  **The custom config is used**  message displayed in your terminal.

You can find a complete [tutorial here](https://www.techiediaries.com/ionic-angular-typeorm-custom-webpack-configuration/) and an [example project here](https://github.com/LucasHenriqueAbreu/todo)